# How to store the result set of a stored procedure into a table, where the result set from SP is in json path?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a stored procedure, where i need to pass the variables with it.

The result set i get is in json path from the above sp.

Now, i want to open the json and stored the result into a table.

i want the syntax for the above?????

In sql server.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a table to match the resultant data from the SPROC.

Then you can insert the results of your SPROC into that table.

```
INSERT INTO Your_Table EXECUTE Your_Stored_Proceedure;
```

Comment: resultant data from the SPROC is in json path, not in table format, if not your syntax would have been easily executed

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the resultset of the stored procedure into a NVARCHAR(MAX) variable, you can use OPENJSON to get resultset. [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)

EXEC @json = StoredProcedureReturningJSON @parameters...
```

Now, you need to parse the JSON Result into a table structure. [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

See example below

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json =   
  N'[  
       {  
         "Order": {  
           "Number":"SO43659",  
           "Date":"2011-05-31T00:00:00"  
         },  
         "AccountNumber":"AW29825",  
         "Item": {  
           "Price":2024.9940,  
           "Quantity":1  
         }  
       },  
       {  
         "Order": {  
           "Number":"SO43661",  
           "Date":"2011-06-01T00:00:00"  
         },  
         "AccountNumber":"AW73565",  
         "Item": {  
           "Price":2024.9940,  
           "Quantity":3  
         }  
      }  
 ]'  

SELECT * FROM  
 OPENJSON ( @json )  
WITH (   
              Number   varchar(200) '$.Order.Number' ,  
              Date     datetime     '$.Order.Date',  
              Customer varchar(200) '$.AccountNumber',  
              Quantity int          '$.Item.Quantity'  
 )
```

Comment: create table t(a int,b varchar(10)).......insert into t values(1,'ram'),(2,sita),(3,'rahul)...........create proc spdetails as select * from t for json path,include_null_values................................Now i want the result set from execution of spdetails into a table......................i tried declaring variable with nvarchar(max) and tried to store, but the data cant be stored in variable as like.........declare @result nvarchar(max) = (exec spdetails)............not working!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: or declare @result nvarchar(max)...........exec @result= spdetails.............. not working